# Python logic - how do I code the maximum weight for two roads that have a variety of maximum weight values?

Tags: python, max, min

The python logic problem involves the simple function min() and max().

You can see the problem described [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a66xY.jpg).

> Part #2: Now we will tell you the whole story. There is also a second route consisting of two bridges, the first with weight limit d, and the second with weight limit e, as illustrated below.
>
> Your truck can take either route. Write a program that prints out the maximum weight that can be transported between the two cities. Assume that the variables a, b, c, d, and contain the bridge weight limits.

I've tried `print(min(a,b,c)` or `min(d,e))`

`print(min(a,b,c), min(d,e))`

`print(min(a,b,c)` and `min(d,e))`

Do I need an if statement, depending on which route the user takes?

Comment: I'm new to coding. print(max(min(a,b,c),min(d,e))) worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this all in one expression, but let's break it up to make it easier to understand.

First, what's the maximum weight that can be transported on route 1? You already know this part:

```
route1 = min(a, b, c)
```

And the same for route 2:

```
route2 = min(d, e)
```

Now, a truck can take either route, so he'll take whichever one allows transporting the most, so:

```
route_best = max(route1, route2)
```

And now you just need to print that out:

```
print(route_best)
```

Comment: The other guy helped. Your answer is much better. This way makes the code in one line. print(max(min(a,b,c),min(d,e))) Thanks and enjoy the points!

Answer (score 1):

The one line answer is:

```
print max(min(a,b,c), min(d,e))
```

What is that example from?